# Multiple use of function that reads from a file

Tags: loops, ifstream

In my program I have function `Get_auto()`;
I want it to do something like this:

```
void Cook::Get_auto(){  
ifstream ifile;
ifile.open("sourcek.txt");
char choice;
ifile >> choice;
switch (choice)
{
case '0': lvl = 0;
    break;
case '1': lvl = 1;
    break;
case '2': lvl = 2;
    break;
case '3': lvl = 3;
    break;
case '4': lvl = 4;
    break;
}
}
```

The problem is that I want to use the Get_auto function multiple times, each time loading the data below the last used part of a file.
How should I do this?

Comment: consider using a static_cast of your char to an int. You may find out you have more than 9 lvls in which case use strings and consider a function called atoi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the ifstream to the class as its private field. Then, create a method `Cook::open`, where you open the ifstream. In `Cook::Get_auto` only use the `>>` operator. Call the `open` method before you call the `Get_auto` method for the first time.

Something like this: (assuming its a C++ code, this will be in the header file)

```
private:
    ifstream ifile;

public:
    void open();
    void Get_auto();
```

and this will be in the source file:

```
void Cook::open() {
    ifile.open("sourcek.txt");
}

void Cook::Get_auto(){  
    char choice;
    ifile >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case '0': lvl = 0;
        break;
    case '1': lvl = 1;
        break;
    case '2': lvl = 2;
        break;
    case '3': lvl = 3;
        break;
    case '4': lvl = 4;
        break;
    }
}
```

It would be wise also to add some checking whether `ifile` is open and whether you can read from it.